# How do I test a magento module?

Tags: testing

I have recently installed this ([module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/display-attribute-grouped-by-attribute-sets.html)). There is no documentation(how to install, how to use etc). So i copied the files manually(didnt use magento connect), clear the caches, logged out and re -login from admin and nothing happened. I checked in the configuration/advanced and it is enabled. I also checked the system.log files (it is empty). So my question : is there a method to check if my module is working or not ? How do I test it ?

Comment: Did you find the plugin in System>Config>Advanced

Comment: yes i find int and it is enabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you installed a module, it must be for a reason. In this case I assume you wanted to display the product attributes grouped by the attribute group.
In order to test that, just visit a product page and see if the display matches your expectations.

If it doesn't work, there is always the chance your design is not compatible with the extension.
To check that, revert to the default theme and see if it looks ok on it.
If it does...start digging for differences in your theme relative to the default one.
Also there is a chance that you have custom extension interfering with this one.
Test the extension on a vanilla install and see if it works there.
If it does...again...start digging.
If it doesn't it means the extension is c**p and you can skip it.  Or you can contact the developer for support.

Comment: what do you mean by vanilla install ?

Comment: @Chester. Clean copy.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have copied all files. Double check everything. Most likely you've missed the /app/etc/modules/{module}.xml. This file tells Magento about the extension. Whether its enabled , any dependancies and what code pool it resides in. (local or community)